# Get, edit, and replace string with regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to

1. Get a part of my strings analysed with regex
2. Edit it (replacing in this part the ' ' character by a '_')
3. Replace the part 1. Get function by the string obtained in part 2.

I see that Python has a re library with the function sub, but I don't know how to get the full match of the regex.

A little code, maybe it will be a little more clear:

```
s = 'contrat bail habitation'
print re.sub(r'(contrat)\s', ???.replace(' ', '_'), s)
```

I want to replace contrat by contrat_ (this is just for the example, the full process I work on will be more complex, but I prefer to begin with an easy part). 
In place of the ???, I don't know what to put to get what I obtained with `r'(contrat)\s'`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use `re.sub(rx, lambda x: x.group().replace(' ', '_'), s)`

Comment: Well done, thank you ! You should answer me no in comment, i would  have noted your answer as the solution !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a lambda expression as the replacment argument:

```
re.sub(rx, lambda x: x.group().replace(' ', '_'), s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From the [`re.sub` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> *repl* can be a string or a function... If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

Comment: Dude, that is so cool.  I feel like I'm stuck in an infinite loop of not being able to love Python any more, then I see a post like this and fall in love harder.